# Modificación de parámetro puntero como si fuera Paso por referencia c++

Tags: c++, punteros, programación-funcional, inteligencia-artificial, paso-por-referencia

tal y como dice el título tengo una función que está modificando el valor del parámetro que se le pasa a la función como si estuviera pasado por referencia, este es el código de C++:

```
tEstado* aplicaOperador(unsigned op, tEstado* t)
{
    tEstado *s = (tEstado*)malloc(sizeof(tEstado));
    memcpy(&s, &t, sizeof(tEstado));
    int x = s->x;
    int y = s->y;
    switch(op)
    {
       case ARRIBA: s->x--; s->mapa[x][y] = '0'; s->mapa[x-1][y] = 'X';
           break;
       case ABAJO: s->x++; s->mapa[x][y] = '0'; s->mapa[x+1][y] = 'X';
           break;
       case IZQ: s->y--; s->mapa[x][y] = '0'; s->mapa[x][y-1] = 'X';
          break;
       case DER: s->y++; s->mapa[x][y] = '0'; s->mapa[x][y+1] = 'X';
          break;
  }

   return s;
}
```

Pienso que puede ser debido a memcpy, pero tengo entendido que lo único que hace es copiar los datos del origen al destino y no la dirección de memoria.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
memcpy(&s, &t, sizeof(tEstado));
```

*memcpy* recibe punteros a las posiciones que copiar, pero *s* y *t* ya son punteros.

Al usar las referencias *memcpy* no copia los datos a los que apunta *t*, copia *t*. Básicamente haces *s = t;*<sup>1</sup>.

Haz

```
memcpy(s, t, sizeof(tEstado));
```

<sup>1</sup>En realidad, como copias *sizeof(tEstado)* bytes, salvo que *sizeof(tEstado)* sea igual a *sizeof(tEstado** *)*, estarás copiando cosas de manera inadecuada y puede suceder cualquier error. Así que no es exactamente *s = t;*, pero en tu caso no parece haber efectos secundarios.